# How do I use functions from my file.c in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

How can I use functions from my file.c in Objective C
I tried #include < file.c > in file2.m where I want to call this functions and got Lexical or Prepocesor Issue < file.c > not found and when I use #include "file" i got Apple Mach-O Linker (ID) Error. Same errors when I use #import instead of #include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `file.c` have a `file.h` with the function declarations? You will want to `#include` that, and also make sure that `file.c` is compiled and linked in.

Comment: a - ok! I have just one file.c and fuction declarations and implemetations are in this file. So I have to create file.h and move my function declarations to that file?

Answer (score 1):

If in "file.m" you have a function like this:

```
void hello()
{
    printf("Hello world!");
}
```

You also have to create a header file possibly called "file.h" in which you only declare the function but don't actually implement it;

```
void hello();
```

Then you have to `#import` or `#include` thw file.h file from file2.m.